# How do I remove all non numeric values in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So if I do an input command:

`input("pick a number")`

How do I remove all non numeric numbers in that string?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make the user enter a valid number?

Comment: Please give an example of the expected input and expected results.

Comment: What is a "non numeric number"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub()` to remove all characters that match a pattern.

```
import re

answer = input("pick a number")
number = int(re.sub(r'\D', '', answer))
```

The regexp pattern `\D` matches any character that isn't a numeric digit, it's replaced with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

its better to have the user input the *right* answer

```
x = int(input("pick a number"))
```

Comment: How do I tell if the input is an integer or something else?

Comment: well, w/ that it will always give the value an integer (or error if it can't cast it).